# Find the supremum of the following set:

Tags: analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Find the supremum of the following set and justify why:
$$
A:= \left\{\frac{n^{2}+6}{n+8} \ \Bigg|\ n\in\mathbb{N}\right\} .
$$

Comment: What have you tried? Don't dump [your homework](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1987690/find-the-supremum-of-the-following-set) here, please.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\frac{n^{2}+6}{n+8}\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Ok thank you, and how would you prove formally that the set has no upper bound or would the above observation be sufficient? Thanks!

Comment: Well, given any $M<\infty$, by the above observation, there is an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{n^{2}+6}{n+8}>M$. Thus, $A$ can have no finite upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any upper bound to $\frac{n^2+6}{n+8}$? Can you find any number that is larger than $\frac{n^2+6}{n+8}$ for all $n$?

What if instead of $\frac{n^2+6}{n+8}$ you just had $\frac{n^2}{n} = n$? Do the additional constants change the asymptotic behavior for large $n$? What does that tell you about the possibility of any finite supremum?